How can i get a gui (pycharm) to accept my fake middle click?
I am using KDE, I setup a custom keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+5 that maps to the command. xdotool click 2 which sends a middle click.
I have also tried with
xte "mouseclick 2" and pyautogui.middleClick() with python.
All of these options work fine for the most part. Except I have two problems.
Pycharm seems to totally ignore the click event.
firefox for some reason prepends a > to the output.
As I've been trouble shooting this I realized that it works totally fine if i run the commands from a terminal that was started in the same desktop session.
Like i have terminator right next to pycharm and i type the command.
sleep 5; xdotool click 2 and then move my cursor over to pycharm it comes through just fine. Also the > is not prepended in firefox.
So I'm guessing that both pycharm and firefox are detecting that this is fake somehow.
I really bad work around that I have is this.
krunner "/usr/local/bin/middle_click" & sleep 0.15; xdotool key Return. That will start krunner with the command and then press return after a short delay. However its terribly hacky to have the little popup showup momentarily. As well as its a quite brittle.
So the commands that I run from krunner work ok. but If its a command that was started from a "Custom Shortcut" section of the KDE settings then it doesn't work.
I tried playing with some environment variables in the script XDG_RUNTIME DISPLAY DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS but none of those seemed to help.
My guess is that it needs to be a proper subprocess of the desktop that the application is running in but I'm not really sure whats going on to be honest.
Another option I tried was running a flask server from the current desktop and then calling the endpoint in my "Custom Shortcut" action, and that actually works as well. Probably what I'll end up doing if I can't find a better solution.
At any rate. Does anyone know why these applications are not processing my middle click events properly? And what i can do to get them accepted by the app?

You could try using xbindkeys. It can run as a daemon process.
